# Assigning variable by value/reference

Tags: typescript

Consider the below code.

```
originalVar: string[] = ["value1","value1","value1"]; 
varWithAdition: string[] = originalVar;
varWithAdition.push("test")
```

When we push the value to varWithAdition the item will also be pushed to originalVar, because we are intrinsically passing by reference it seems.

There must be a way to tell TypeScript to assign/pass variables by value without serializing and deserializing the variable with JSON methods or other such hacks when working with more complex objects or situations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to assign/pass variables by value.

So you you have some options for cloning value (not reference) of array.

First option is array spreads (`[...originalVar]`) to copy your array

```
var originalVar: string[] = ["value1","value1","value1"]; 

var varWithAdition: string[] = [...originalVar]
```

Second option is `slice()` method:

```
var originalVar: string[] = ["value1","value1","value1"]; 

var varWithAdition: string[] = originalVar.slice()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBA9mCWDmsB2IA2A1cBGAXBAzgC5xLwDaAuhALwRkBEoqArgKZb0A0jabH3TPvQoBuCAChxoSNIDqsQgAsAggBMFsKElwFiyclVpkAdKZgJkaTGCwUp4eUrUatWYwAdm%20RQAp6hViJ6AEoRSQBjLXwoVFZjVCh4HzkFFXVCTW1g8UikaNj4xJ9zRBQMbGzJaWg4UqtwPCISAxo6HhZ2LnahAV5O0Ql7GQdU5wytRr1SSlaSy3KwY3xUWHDWH2yUp3TMjy9ff0DCELCcqJi4hKSttJckbNz8y6K5sutgoA) for both sample.